# NullPointerException in codelabs Android CameraX tutorial example code

Tags: android-camerax

Following along with [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#1), and on step 2 "Create the project", I run the app, as requested at the last line, and it crashes immediately with the following logcat:

```
07-28 17:33:45.496 24221-24221/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.android.packageinstaller, PID: 24221
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.computePermissionGrantState(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:293)
        at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.updateDefaultResults(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:343)
        at com.android.packageinstaller.permission.ui.GrantPermissionsActivity.onCreate(GrantPermissionsActivity.java:100)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

It seems the manifest entries they mention in step 3 of the tutorial are necessary to avoid this NullPointerException. Maybe this is just an error in the tutorial, in that the final step should not include a screenshot or the sentance:

> Run the code, it should look like this:

Or is this something that has been updated in cameraX since the writing of this tutorial such that the step 2 code cannot run alone any longer?

Also, I'm not familiar with Kotlin, but are these permissions something that can be done outside the manifest, but instead within the MainActivity.kt file? From what I am familiar with in Java, these had to be included in the Manifest, but I could be wrong about this as well.

#### Edit1:

Adding build details for clarity:
Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1

Android Studio 4.0
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 21, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 5.3.0-46-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1981M
Cores: 8
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: PlantUML integration, SequenceDiagram, org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.google.services.firebase, com.intellij.marketplace, com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.intellij.plugins.markdown, org.pmesmeur.sketchit, ru.leoklo.stackuml, simpleUML

#### Edit2 (Added Manifest before/after Step 3 of tutorial):

Before (End of Step 2 in tutorial...i.e default for empty activity)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jp.oist.cameraxapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

After (After initial section in Step 3 in tutorial)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jp.oist.cameraxapp">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you add your `AndroidManifest.xml` where you've added permissions?

Comment: Added in under heading `Edit2` within question. To reiterate though, the purpose of the question was whether these manifest permissions can be absent, and still get the required camera permissions from the Kotlin code alone. Whether or not this is possible would allow me to determine if the codelabs tutorial step 2 instructions have an error in the Kotlin code (i.e. missing lines of code), or in simply the request for the user to try and run prior to adding the manifest entries documented in their [step 3](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#2)

Comment: This null pointer exception normally occurs when permissions are not declared properly in `AndroidManifest.xml`. There doesn't seem to be an issue in the codelabs code sample. You cannot request runtime permissions without first declaring them in your manifest.

Comment: Alright. I will follow up with codelabs and recommend they update their step 2 wording then (as it currently implies one should be able to build and run without these manifest entries).